# Mocking in RSpec2 causes singleton can't be dumped in Sinatra controller

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, sinatra, rspec2

I'm trying to write a rspec2 test which gives me an error instead. I know the test is not testing anything particular right now. But I'll add some more code later, I'd like to pass this part first.

```
context "/login/twitter" do
        before(:each) do
            request_token = double("request_token")
            request_token.stub(:authorize_url).and_return("http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token")

            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authentication_request_token).and_return(request_token)
            get '/login/twitter'
        end

        it "should redirect to twitter authorized url" do
            last_response.header["Location"].should include "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token"
        end

        it "should redirect back to home page if error occurs" do

        end
    end
```

And this is my controller

```
get '/login/twitter' do
  begin
    request_token = TwitterService.new.authentication_request_token

    session[:request_token_twitter] = request_token

    logger.info(request_token.authorize_url)

    redirect request_token.authorize_url
  rescue Exception => e
    logger.error(e.message)
    redirect '/'
  end  
end
```

And this is the error I got

```
  1) Server /login/twitter should redirect to twitter authorized url
     Failure/Error: get '/login/twitter'
     TypeError:
       singleton can't be dumped
     # ./spec/twitter_route_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Not sure what I have missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to stick something in the session it needs to be serialised, and your mock object can't be serialised - the implementation of rspec mocks would appear to use singletons or define singleton methods

You could try and figure out what methods you need to stub out in order to pretend that the object can be dumped (perhaps `dump`), personally I would just make the test request token be a struct of something similar.